# Typescript error when using array.map in a function

Tags: arrays, typescript

```
interface Object1{
    id:number,
    label:string
}

interface Object2{
    id:number,
    description:string
}


const transformArray:Object2[] = (input:Object1[])=>{
    return input.map(item=>{
        return {
            id:item.id,
            description:item.label
        }
    })
}
```

In this code typescript gives the error

> Type '(input: Object1[]) => { id: number; description: string; }[]' is
> missing the following properties from type 'Object2[]': pop, push,
> concat, join, and 28 more.ts(2740) index.tsx(44, 34): Did you mean to
> call this expression?

I'm trying to create a function that takes an array of Object1 and converts to array of Object2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
const transformArray:Object2[] = (input:Object1[])=>{
```

means that you are saying `transformArray` is of type `Object2[]`. And then you assigning a function to it. An array and a function are not compatible types, so you get a type error.

---

I think you meant to do this:

```
const transformArray = (input:Object1[]): Object2[] => {
```

Here you declare a function that accepts an array of `Object1`s and returns an array of `Object2`s. `transformArray` does not require an explicit type because the function your are assigning to it very strongly typed and Typescript can figure out the tight type from that.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=12&ssc=57&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgIwDeAsAFDLnLAAmAXCAK4C260ANKRcgDZwtc0BnMFFABzUgF9SpUJFiIUGbLgBMxMhWp0mLKOw3kqEAQhEAHMMAD2IQcLGTpJUghtDkwuCAEwrURgCCUFBwAJ7IALzIABSgZvRgNEo4+ADaALoAlDRoWCkqGZEAfMjqnFAQYPRQIJQg8WAAdIxwZrGQjBFFZZwUFVU1pRy9I1rAHY3U+iMjRibmljY04xCMjTx8wyNSBsgSmZJAA)